# loop para replicar um dataframe no R

Tags: r, loop, dataframe

Eu tenho o seguinte dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = 1:7,x2 = 8:14, x3 = 15:21, x4 = 23:29, x5 = 30:36)
```

preciso replicar o valor de cada linha 150, 100, 60, 43 vezes e para cada colunas.

Tentei `rep(df$x1, each=150)`, que replica cada valor das linhas 150 vezes, mas não aceita `rep(df$x1, each=c(150,100,60,43))`... Pensei em fazer através de um loop com for para as linhas de cada coluna.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
    df$out[i] <- rep(df[,i])
    
   
     for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$out[i] <- rep(df[i,])
      
    }
    print(df$out)
}
```

Entretanto não estou conseguindo avançar. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Pode fornecer um exemplo de como deseja o resultado final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A saída esperada não está clara,

- pode ser a base repetida `times` vezes, para cada valor em `times`;
- pode ser cada uma das linhas repetida `times` vezes, também para cada valor em `times`.

Eis duas maneiras de fazer o que está acima.
Primeiro os dados:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = 1:7,x2 = 8:14, x3 = 15:21, x4 = 23:29, x5 = 30:36)
times <- c(150, 100, 60, 43)
```

### A base inteira repetida `times` vezes

```
i <- unlist(lapply(times, \(x) rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), times = x)))
df[i, ]
```

### Cada linha repetida `times` vezes

```
j <- unlist(lapply(times, \(x) rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = x)))
df[j, ]
```

Comment: Desculpe por não ter deixado a saída clara, mesmo assim você me respondeu. Muito obrigada! Eu desejava a segunda opção (j)!